# Does cursor pagination know "on its own" then cursor for the next page?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-pagination

In my project I have installed jscroll:

```
npm i jscroll
```

And I have made the following js (`myjs.js`):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#scroll').jscroll({
        loadingHtml: '<div class="customRow">' +
            '<div class="deltaLabel w-100 d-flex justify-content-center"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-notch fa-spin"></i></div>'+
            '</div>',
        nextSelector: 'a.jscroll-next:last',
        contentSelector: 'div.customRow',
    });

});
```

That is loaded upon this view (users.blade.js):

```
<div id="scroll" style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 58vh;">

@foreach($users as $user)
<div class="row">
{{$user->email}}
</div>
@endforeach

@if ($users->hasMorePages())
  <a class="jscroll-next" href="{{ $users->nextPageUrl() }}"></a>
@endif

</div>
```

I also made a simple route:

```
Route::get('/users',function(Request $request){
  $users = User::orderBy('id')->cursorPaginate(200);
  return view('users',['versions'=>$users]);
});
```

But it seem kinda vague upon how `cursorPaginate` takes the next cursor. Also in case I want to do some searching for example:

```
Route::get('/users',function(Request $request){
   
  $email = $request->get('email',null)


  $users = User::orderBy('id')
  $users->where('email',$email)->cursorPaginate(200);
  return view('users',['versions'=>$users]);
});
```

How my route will know the next page. Using SQL Server and trying this:

```
Route::get('/users',function(Request $request){
  $cursor = $request->input('cursor', null);
  $users = User::orderBy('id')->cursorPaginate(200,$cursor);
  return view('users',['versions'=>$users]);
});
```

I get the following error in SQL Server:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'eyJpZCI6MjAwLCJfcG9pbnRzVG9OZXh0SXRlbXMiOnRydWV9'. (Connection: sqlsrv, SQL: select top 201 [eyJpZCI6MjAwLCJfcG9pbnRzVG9OZXh0SXRlbXMiOnRydWV9] from [users] where ([id] > 200) order by [id] asc) in file /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 822
```

Therefore how I can know what is the next cursor in my route and use that to fetch data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But it seem kinda vague upon how cursorPaginate takes the next cursor. Also in case I want to do some searching for example:

It is not vague because you can provide the cursor paginator as:

```
Route::get('/users',function(Request $request){
  $cursor = $request->input('cursor', null);
  $users = User::orderBy('id')->cursorPaginate(200,['*'],'cursor',$cursor);
  return view('users',['versions'=>$users]);
});
```

But still I don't know if searching does affect the result.